# oracle sql- multiple aggregations: select max((integer to date)) & sum(items) at max date

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I have this example table:

```
group|type|sold|date
x      1  10  201801
x      1  44  201705
y      3  33  201801
y      3  3   201705
x      2  10  201701
```

I'm having trouble returning:
one record for each group and type, with the amount sold at the most recent date. date is an integer

i.e.

```
group|type|sold|date
x      1  10  201801
y      3  33  201801
x      2  10  201701
```

I tried selecting each `column, sum(sold), max(cast(date to int))`, grouping the rest, but it doesn't work.

I tried `WHERE date IN (select max(date))`. I couldn't get that to work either.
This is much trickier than I thought!

Comment: oracle, i assumed the solution would be very similar for this issue. apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple application of the aggregate `LAST()` function (many developers choose to ignore it, for reasons that escape me). I use `sum(sold)` just in case there are several rows for the same `max` date in a group.

Please note that `GROUP` and `DATE` (and `TYPE`, too, actually) are Oracle keywords and should not be used as column names. I changed `GROUP` to `GRP` and `DATE` to `DT`, and you should do the same.

```
select   grp, type, sum(sold) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) as sold, max(dt) as dt
from     <table_name>
group by grp, type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`  if you like. I have used the column names `date_t` and `group_t` instead of date and group resp.

```
SELECT group_t,
       TYPE,
       sold,
       date_t
FROM   (SELECT group_t,
               TYPE,
               sold,
               date_t,
               row_number()
                 over (
                   PARTITION BY group_t, TYPE
                   ORDER BY date_t DESC ) rn
        FROM   table1)
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY date_t DESC;
```